# Getting Post details when post is published

Tags: plugins, customization

I would like to collect main info about post like Title etc. **in moment when post was written and it's going to be published** and perform some actions on this data. What's the hook for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is [`wp_insert_post()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/post.php#L2149), and as you can see there are some hooks you can use to modify data. [`wp_insert_post_data`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) is a filter that gets all data right before it will be inserted into the database, so you modify it there and don't need to do anything to get it saved. At the end of the function you can see the [`save_post`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/save_post) action and its equivalent [`wp_insert_post`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_insert_post), which are more appropriate if you want to *do* something (instead of *change* something).

These functions are fired when a post is saved, not only when it is published. For the publish action, look at [`wp_transition_post_status()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/post.php#L2714), which has three hooks:

- `transition_post_status`, called with the new and old statuses, and the post data
- `{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}`, like `draft_to_publish`, called with the post data
- `{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}`, like `publish_page`, called with the post ID and post data

Answer (score 0):

Also check here: [WordPress prompt checklist before publish?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/wordpress-prompt-checklist-before-publish) "WordPress prompt checklist before publish?"